# How to draw a moving circle in Pygame with a small angle at a low speed and blinking?

Tags: python, pygame

The code below moves two balls on the screen. The first one is moved with an angle of 10 degree at a low speed with a good drawing quality. The second ball is moved with an angle of 1 degree and in order for the angle to be respected, the speed must be much higher and the drawing is unsatisfactory with a lot of blinking. Is there a way to slow down the drawing of the second ball and avoid the excessive blinking ?

```
import pygame, sys, math
from pygame.locals import *

pygame.init()
DISPLAYSURF = pygame.display.set_mode((1000, 600))
pygame.display.set_caption('Bouncing Ball with position and angle')

# Set our color constants
BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
YELLOW = (255, 255, 0)

# Create the ball class
class Ball():
    def __init__(self,
                 screen,
                 color,
                 radius,
                 startX,
                 startY,
                 speed,
                 angle=45):
        super().__init__()
        self.screen = screen
        self.color = color
        rectSize = radius * 2
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(startX, startY, rectSize, rectSize)
        self.speed = speed
        self.angle = math.radians(angle)

    def update(self):
        delta_x = self.speed * math.cos(self.angle)
        delta_y = self.speed * math.sin(self.angle)
        self.rect = self.rect.move(delta_x, delta_y)

        if self.rect.right >= self.screen.get_width() or self.rect.left <= 0:
            self.angle = math.pi - self.angle

        if self.rect.top <= 0 or self.rect.bottom >= self.screen.get_height():
            self.angle = -self.angle

    def draw(self):
        '''
        Draw our ball to the screen with position information.
        '''
        pygame.draw.circle(self.screen, self.color, self.rect.center, int(self.rect.width / 2))

# Create a new Ball instance named 'myball'
myball = Ball(screen=DISPLAYSURF, color=YELLOW, startX=100, startY=100, radius=150, speed=8, angle=10)
mySmaLlAngleball = Ball(screen=DISPLAYSURF, color=YELLOW, startX=100, startY=500, radius=150, speed=58, angle=-1)

run = True
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

# Display loop
while run:
    # Handle events
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()

    # Update ball position
    myball.update()
    mySmaLlAngleball.update()

    # Draw screen
    DISPLAYSURF.fill(BLACK)
    myball.draw()
    mySmaLlAngleball.draw()
    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(30)
```

Answer (score 2):

The issue is caused, because [`pygame.Rect`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html) stores integral coordinates:

> The coordinates for Rect objects are all integers. [...]

The fraction component of `delta_x` and `delta_y` is lost at `self.rect.move(delta_x, delta_y)`.

You have to use floating point numbers for the computation. Add an attribute `self.pos`, which is a tupe with 2 components an stores the center point of a ball:

```py
self.pos = self.rect.center
```

Compute the position with the maximum floating point accuracy:

```py
delta_x = self.speed * math.cos(self.angle)
delta_y = self.speed * math.sin(self.angle)
self.pos = (self.pos[0] + delta_x, self.pos[1] + delta_y)
```

Update the `self.rect.center` by the [`round()`ed](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#round) position.

```py
self.rect.center = round(self.pos[0]), round(self.pos[1])
```

`self.pos` is the "internal" position and responsible for the exact computation of the position. `self.rect.center` is the integral position and responsible to draw the ball. `self.pos` slightly changes in each frame. `self.rect.center` changes only if the a component of the coordinate has changed by 1.

Class `Ball`:

```py
class Ball():
    def __init__(self,
                 screen,
                 color,
                 radius,
                 startX,
                 startY,
                 speed,
                 angle=45):
        super().__init__()
        self.screen = screen
        self.color = color
        rectSize = radius * 2
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(startX, startY, rectSize, rectSize)
        self.speed = speed
        self.angle = math.radians(angle)
        self.pos = self.rect.center

    def update(self):
        delta_x = self.speed * math.cos(self.angle)
        delta_y = self.speed * math.sin(self.angle)
        self.pos = (self.pos[0] + delta_x, self.pos[1] + delta_y)

        self.rect.center = round(self.pos[0]), round(self.pos[1])

        if self.rect.right >= self.screen.get_width() or self.rect.left <= 0:
            self.angle = math.pi - self.angle

        if self.rect.top <= 0 or self.rect.bottom >= self.screen.get_height():
            self.angle = -self.angle

    def draw(self):
        '''
        Draw our ball to the screen with position information.
        '''
        pygame.draw.circle(self.screen, self.color, self.rect.center, int(self.rect.width / 2))
```

---

With this solution you can scale up the flops per second (`clock.tick()`) and scale down the speed by the same scale. This leads to a smooth movement without blinking.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. Just one thing to add so that your solution really impacts the circle drawing: reduce the mySmaLlAngleball speed from 58 in my original code to, say 10. Increase the FPS (frame per second) rate if you wish. Otherwise, the drawing blink will mask the correctness of your answer.

Comment: @Jean-PierreSchnyder You're right. I didn't specifically mention this because I thought my suggestions imply that.